# Most efficient way to populate List<int> via ADO.NET call to stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I’m calling a stored procedure via ADO.NET as shown (in simplified form) below.    The database is a MySQL database.
The stored procedure returns a list of ID values that correspond to calls that need to have their call times rescheduled.
The C# code stores them in a list.

My question is:  Is there a more efficient way to get the values into the C# list, instead of using the DataReader as I’m doing?
I don’t know yet if the way I’m doing it is too inefficient for our application (that will be determined during testing), I’m just looking for a faster strategy, if one exists.

I looked at using a DataSet but, from what I’ve read, that could be slower if the list of ID-s is large (which it could be).
Also, from what I’ve read, LINQ might be slower, as well.

I only need to store the list into callsToRescheduleList; ie, I don’t need to do any random access of the ID-s, so those features of the DataSet are not needed.
I’m just looking for the fastest way to get the data into the list.

Any suggestions?

The C# code:

```
private void GetCallsToRescheduleList()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
   ( 
       "`phytel`.`spPhy_GetCallsToRescheduleListPreviousDays`", 
       (MySqlConnection) DatabaseConnection,  workerTransaction
   );
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
        while( reader.Read())
        {
            callsToRescheduleList.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
        }
   }
}
```

The MySQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spPhy_GetCallsToRescheduleListPreviousDays` ()
BEGIN
       SELECT
             id
       FROM callrequest
       WHERE
             dialerCampaignId = 'CATH001’
             AND
             status = 'SCHEDULED’
    ;
END
```

Comment: You can look into an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that's about as good as it gets - the select is narrow, and use of the reader ordinal overload in the tight loop is good.

Some checks:

- Ensure that there is an index (key) on `(dialerCampaignId, status)` in MySql - I'm assuming there is better selectivity on `dialerCampaignId` here.
- If there is a chance that your `List<Int>` consumer won't iterate the full list every time, as an alternative to rolling the data up into a list, consider also using an enumerable and yield return:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetCallsToRescheduleListPreviousDays()
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand
    ( 
       "`phytel`.`spPhy_GetCallsToRescheduleListPreviousDays`", 
       (MySqlConnection) DatabaseConnection,  workerTransaction
    )
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
           while( reader.Read())
           {
               yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
           }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Also remember to Dispose of `IDisposable` resources like `Commands` and `Readers`